# Pasting to one column based on criteria in another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste a range of formulas from one worksheet to another.
In the target worksheet, the code looks for criteria in column A, then if met, pasts in column H. It goes from the last used cell up.
I am sure this is entry level stuff but if someone can assist that would be greatly appreciated.
Code below

```
Sub Step8()

'Copies cells from worksheet called "Bi-Weekly"

    Worksheets("Bi-Weekly").Activate
    Range("H16:BK16").Copy


'Go to target worksheet called "Report"

    Worksheets("Report").Activate

    Dim lRow As Long


'find last row

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop from the last row to the first (finishing at row 17)

    For i = lRow To 17 Step -1

'Where column A = "No", paste copied cells to column H (to BK) from original worksheet

    If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = "No" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i).Paste
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of activating, copying and pasting, try assigning values from one sheet to another. Moreover, there are many posts about how to avoid for-loops when want to paste into filtered ranges.

Comment: Hi M-M, I am teaching myself VBA on the go, but that said, would you please direct me to an alternate solution for this.  Right now it is getting stuck on the line   ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i).Paste

Comment: Where's the problem?  What line is highlighted when you click Debug Button?

Comment: Easiest way to do this to avoid a for-loop (that I can think of) is sorting `Report` based on `Column A` and then paste the value to all the rows with `No`. You can get the most of the code by recording a macro. If you want to go back to the original sorting, then you can add a dummy id column at first.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry, I missed your question.  The debug highlighted "ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i).Paste".  My question is solved however, but thank you for enquiring.  Thanks also M-M.  I am going to try the second code option also.

Answer (score 1):

## Copy Formulas

### The Code

```
Sub Step8()

    Const cSource As String = "Bi-Weekly" ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const cRange  As String = "H16:BK16"  ' Source Range Address
    Const cTarget As String = "Report"    ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const cColCrit As Variant = 1         ' Target Criteria Column Letter/Number
    Const cColTgt As Variant = "H"        ' Target Column Letter/Number
    Const cfRow As Long = 17              ' Target First Row
    Const cCrit As String = "No"          ' Target Criteria

    Dim rng As Range  ' Source Range
    Dim lRow As Long  ' Target Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long     ' Target Worksheet Row Counter

    ' Create a reference to the Source Range (rng).
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource).Range(cRange)
    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
        ' Calculate Last Row Number (lRow)
        ' from Target Criteria Column (cColCrit).
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cColCrit).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Loop through rows (cells) of Target Worksheet starting from First Row.
        For i = cfRow To lRow
            ' When the cell at the intersection of the current row (i)
            ' and the Target Criteria Column (cColCrit) contains
            ' the Target Criteria (cCrit).
            If .Cells(i, cColCrit).Value = cCrit Then
                ' Copy Source Range (rng) to the cell at the intersection
                ' of the current row (i) and Target Column (cColTgt).
                rng.Copy .Cells(i, cColTgt)
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

### No Constants Version

```
Sub Step8NoConstants()

    Dim rng As Range  ' Source Range
    Dim lRow As Long  ' Target Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long     ' Target Worksheet Row Counter

    ' Create a reference to the Source Range (rng).
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bi-Weekly").Range("H16:BK16")
    ' In Worksheet "Report".
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
        ' Calculate Last Row Number (lRow) from column 1 ("A").
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Loop through rows (cells) of worksheet "Report" starting from row 17.
        For i = 17 To lRow
            ' When the cell at the intersection of the current row (i)
            ' and column 1 ("A") contains "No".
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "No" Then
                ' Copy Source Range (rng) to the cell at the intersection
                ' of the current row (i) and column "H".
                rng.Copy .Cells(i, "H")
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It is going to take me a bit of time to digest all the code you have used here, but it worked perfectly, thank you so much VBasic2008.

Comment: @JohnJac: I've edited the comments. Might be helpful.

Comment: They help for sure. You are the master! Thanks a lot